# Is there any command which give from a specific numeric column how many times a number exists?

Tags: r

Having a specific column like this number_of_columns_with_text:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), number_of_columns_with_text = c(3,2,1,3,1,1))
```

Is there any command which could give the sum of the numbers exists in this column (how many times a number exists).

Example output

```
data.frame(number = c(1,2,3), volume = c(3,1,2))
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(t(table(df$number_of_columns_with_text)))`

Comment: or `dplyr::count(df, number_of_columns_with_text)`

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is `table(...)`

```
> table(df$number_of_columns_with_text)
1 2 3 
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you can first `group_by` the variable you want to tabulate and then use `n()` to count the frequencies of the distinct values:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(number_of_columns_with_text)%>%
  summarise(volume = n())
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  number_of_columns_with_text volume
                        <dbl>  <int>
1                           1      3
2                           2      1
3                           3      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
group_by(number_of_columns_with_text) %>% 
count()
```